# Wiring a new pendant light

Tags: wiring

There is 2 white and 2 blacks in the ceiling box, the new pendant has 1 of each, do I put all 3 blacks together and all 3 whites together?

Comment: How was the box previously wired? Are there any other lights controlled by the same switch?

Comment: generally that's the case, but mistakes can be made by the original installers. Still, you have good odds of that being correct, and there's only a few permutations ;)...

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the switch box for the switch controlling this light?

Comment: You disconnect the previous light and attach the new light to the wires it was connected to, without messing with any other connections. If you just ignore how it was connected before and group all wires by color, you have *excellent* odds of finding that the breaker trips when you flip the switch. Drop "switch loop" into the search box and you'll see why...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe! Be sure the power is off. Get your ohmmeter and place it across one set of leads (black and white) See if it shows a short or open. Then watching the ohmmeter flip every switch in the room and see if it changes. If it does that pair is going to a switch, if not try again with the other pair. Try again and see if one of them changes the ohmmeter. Odds are high one of the pairs will.  This is how you would wire it. Here is a link with a good explanation. The image is copyrighted by https://www.buildmyowncabin.com/
[image] Here is the link, it disappeared on me. https://community.smartthings.com/t/automated-switches-what-should-my-wiring-look-like-us-version/15473